# Headers table in landscape

Tags: header-footer, longtable, landscape

Any suggestions to produce these headers:

Desired output(others' suggestions to make the table readable are welcome)
PS: we need to keep the landscape

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[font={large,bf}]{caption} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{ambiguity mu phi 101}
     \label{tab:ambiguity mu phi 101}
\resizebox{1.34\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\toprule
\toprule
& \multicolumn{ 4}{c}{\textbf{2001}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2001}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2002}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2002}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2003}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2003}}  \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-13}
\cmidrule(lr){14-17}
\cmidrule(lr){18-21}
\cmidrule(lr){22-25}
& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T1$ } & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T2$} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T3$ } & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T4$} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T1$} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T2$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T3$ } & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T4$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T1$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T2$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T3$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T4$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
\cmidrule(lr){12-13}
\cmidrule(lr){14-15}
\cmidrule(lr){16-17}
\cmidrule(lr){18-19}
\cmidrule(lr){20-21}
\cmidrule(lr){22-23}
\cmidrule(lr){24-25}
   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}\\
\cmidrule{2-25}
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0$}& -0,046&-1,063&-0,058&-2,534&-0,072&-0,924&-0,053&-1,215&-0,053&-2,315&-0,053&-1,065&-0,131&-0,917&-0,090&-1,236&0,011& 0,000&  0,009&  0,000&  0,009&  0,000&  0,120&  3,270\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}$\xi=0.5$& -0,046 &-1,063&   -0,058& -2,534& -0,072& -0,924& -0,053& -1,215& -0,053& -2,315& -0,053& -1,065& -0,131& -0,917& -0,090& -1,236&-0,015&  -0,309& 0,000&  -0,222& 0,032&  0,437&  0,120&  3,270\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}$\xi=1$ &-0,053 &-1,147& -0,056& -2,490& -0,074& -0,950& -0,066& -1,442& -0,068& -2,780& -0,067& -1,276& -0,131& -0,917& -0,090& -1,236&-0,024&  -0,414& -0,004& -0,332& 0,046&  0,713&  0,120&  3,270\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}$\xi=2$& -0,086 &-1,546& -0,089& -3,382& -0,100& -1,198& -0,092& -1,898& -0,094& -3,636& -0,092& -1,672& -0,131& -0,917& -0,113& -1,507&-0,036&  -0,551& -0,008& -0,442& 0,059&  0,949&  0,141&  3,880\\
\bottomrule
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0$}&0,114&  3,716&  0,102&  4,269&  0,065&  2,671&  0,053&  1,780&  0,053&  1,306&  0,051&  1,377&  0,062&  1,951&  0,073&  2,260&  0,058&  1,004&  0,059&  0,601&  0,059&  0,806&0,056&    0,586\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0.5$}&0,114&    3,716&  0,102&  4,269&  0,065&  2,671&  0,053&  1,780&  0,053&  1,306&  0,051&  1,377&  0,062&  1,951&  0,073&  2,260&  0,058&  1,004&  0,059&  0,615&  0,059&  0,834&  0,067&  1,395\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=1$}&0,114&  3,716&  0,108&  4,581&  0,073&  3,124&  0,053&  1,780&  0,053&  1,306&  0,051&  1,377&  0,062&  1,951&  0,073&  2,260&  0,058&  1,004&  0,067&  1,097&  0,068   &1,409& 0,076&  2,013\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=2$}&0,139&  4,569&  0,132&  5,735&  0,087&  3,934&  0,062&  2,247&  0,061&  1,725&  0,059&  1,946&  0,062&  1,951&  0,073&  2,260&  0,067&  1,679&  0,081&  1,899&  0,082   &2,385& 0,085   &2,705\\
\bottomrule
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0$}&0,115&3,065&0,078&1,180&0,035&-0,050&   0,033&0,000&0,013&0,000&-0,037&-0,964&-0,053&-0,396&-0,157&-0,980&-0,131&-0,678&    0,002&  0,000&  0,001&  0,000&  0,003   &0,059\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0.5$}&0,115&3,065&0,080&1,278&0,052&0,459&0,036&0,075&-0,001&-0,218&-0,065&-1,449&-0,081&-0,577&-0,157&-0,980&-0,131&   -0,678& -0,030& -0,453& 0,008&  0,105&  0,046&  0,962\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=1$}&0,115&3,065&0,088&1,561&0,054&0,531&0,038&0,113&-0,009&-0,344&-0,107&-2,172&-0,127&-0,864&-0,155&-0,969&-0,150& -0,775& -0,046& -0,678& 0,012&  0,158&  0,065&  1,357\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=2$}&0,115&3,065&0,105&2,217&0,060&0,707&0,040&0,150&-0,022&-0,536&-0,149&-2,892&-0,171&-1,151&-0,211&-1,309&-0,197&-1,012&-0,061&-0,902&    0,015&  0,210&  0,092&  1,918\\
\bottomrule
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0$}&0,110&  3,454&  0,112&  0,915&  0,114&  1,973&  0,117&  3,654&  0,101&  3,142&  0,058&  2,091&  0,055&  0,292&  0,024&  0,429&  0,037&  1,484&  0,048&1,600&    0,048   &1,899& 0,094   &2,843\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0.5$}&0,110&    3,454&  0,112&  0,915&  0,114&  1,973&  0,117&  3,654&  0,101&  3,142&  0,058&  2,091&  0,055&  0,292&  0,026&  0,470&  0,033&  1,330&  0,045&  1,491&  0,045&  1,769&  0,094&  2,843\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=1$}&0,128&  4,040&  0,128&  1,050&  0,114&  1,973&  0,117&  3,654&  0,101&  3,142&  0,063&  2,272&  0,059&  0,316&  0,035&  0,620&  0,054&  2,192&  0,063&  2,092&  0,063&  2,468&  0,094   &2,843\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=2$}&0,173&  5,476&  0,166&  1,364&  0,137&  2,391&  0,117&  3,654&  0,103&  3,204&  0,082&  2,957&  0,076&  0,405&  0,051&  0,922&  0,071&  2,878&  0,083&  2,795&  0,084   &3,305& 0,102&  3,106\\
\bottomrule
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0$}&0,136&  8,292&  0,135&  4,701&  0,165&  5,930&  0,172&  9,036&  0,167&  8,556&  0,145&  10,725& 0,121&  4,511&  0,113&  3,036&  0,020&  0,823&  0,008&  0,223&  0,001&  0,026&  -0,002& -0,111\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0.5$}&0,136&    8,292&  0,135&  4,701&  0,165&  5,930&  0,172&  9,036&  0,167&  8,556&  0,145&  10,725& 0,121&  4,511&  0,113&  3,036&  0,027&  1,146&  0,020&  0,586&  0,010&  0,160&  0,006&  0,138\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=1$}&0,136&  8,292&  0,135&  4,701&  0,165&  5,930&  0,172&  9,036&  0,167&  8,556&  0,145&  10,725& 0,121&  4,511&  0,113&  3,036&  0,042&  1,746&  0,028&  0,834&  0,018&  0,297&  0,007&  0,152\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=2$}&0,136&  8,292&  0,135&  4,701&  0,165&  5,930&  0,172&  9,036&  0,167&  8,556&  0,145&  10,725& 0,121&  4,511&  0,113&3,036&    0,055   &2,317& 0,039&  1,173&  0,026&  0,435&  0,008&  0,203\\
\bottomrule
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0$}&0,006&  0,195&  0,003&  0,029&  0,010&  0,396&  0,062&  2,841&  0,083&  4,892&  0,135&  9,883&  0,141&  14,267& 0,128&  9,260&  
0,130&  2,803&  0,056&  1,428&  0,020&  -0,076& 0,020&  -0,055\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0.5$}&0,006&    0,195&  0,012&  0,367&  0,035&  1,809&  0,062&  2,841&  0,083&  4,892&  0,135&  9,883&  0,141&  14,267& 0,128&  9,260&  
0,130&  2,803&  0,056&  1,428&  0,037&  1,059&  0,038&  0,223\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=1$}&0,014&  0,619&  0,020&  0,705&  0,055&  2,943&  0,067&  3,099&  0,083&  4,892&  0,135&  9,883&  0,141&  14,267& 0,128&  9,260&  
0,130&  2,803&  0,066&  1,808&  0,047&  1,710&  0,047&  0,351\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=2$}&0,016&  0,687&  0,021&  0,737&  0,067&  3,607&  0,083&  3,936&  0,093&  5,554&  0,135&  9,883&  0,141&  14,267& 0,128&  9,260&  
0,130&  2,803&  0,085&  2,537&  0,055&  2,272&  0,055&  0,478\\
\bottomrule
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0$}&0,026&  0,147&  0,018&  -0,115& 0,028&  0,373&  0,023&  0,435&  0,027&  0,089&  0,033&  0,339&  0,059&  0,819&  0,167&  3,170&  0,214   &5,620& 0,229&  9,019&  0,258&  4,754   &0,236& 7,860\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0.5$}&0,026&    0,147&  0,035&  0,611&  0,054&  1,344&  0,051&  1,876&  0,043&  0,144&  0,044&  0,457&  0,059&  0,819&  0,167&  3,170&  0,214   &5,620& 0,229&  9,019&  0,258&  4,754&  0,236&  7,860\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=1$}&0,034&  0,586&  0,042&  0,944&  0,068&  1,868&  0,072&  2,986&  0,067&  0,229&  0,064&  0,672&  0,074&  1,041&  0,167&  3,170&  0,214   &5,620& 0,229&  9,019&  0,258&  4,754&  0,236   &7,860\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=2$}&0,035&  0,629&  0,051&  1,307&  0,090&  2,680&  0,087&  3,742&  0,084&  0,288&  0,087&  0,911&  0,095&  1,342&  0,190&  3,623&  0,214   &5,620& 0,229&  9,019&  0,258&  4,754&  0,236&  7,860\\
\end{tabular}}%
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

my output :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your MWE doesn't reproduce content of the showed table.
- Coloring of cells doesn't work well with `booktabs` rules. They add white gaps above/below cells contents.
- Scaling tables usually has side effect: they mostly become unreadable.
- In MWE I make some changes to table settings, marked are by `% <---`, which make table slightly more readable.
- In MWE below is considered only first four rows in body.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[font={large,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{ambiguity mu phi 101}
     \label{tab:ambiguity mu phi 101}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{                      % <----
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}                       % <----
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{yellow!50}}l     % <----
                cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\toprule
\rowcolor{yellow!50}    % <----
\cellcolor{white}       % <----
& \multicolumn{ 4}{c}{\textbf{2001}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2001}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2002}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2002}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2003}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{2003}}  \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-13}
\cmidrule(lr){14-17}
\cmidrule(lr){18-21}
\cmidrule(lr){22-25}

\rowcolor{green!50}     % <----
\cellcolor{white}       % <----
& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T1$ } & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T2$} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T3$ } & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T4$} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T1$} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T2$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T3$ } & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T4$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T1$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T2$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T3$}& \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{$T4$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
\cmidrule(lr){12-13}
\cmidrule(lr){14-15}
\cmidrule(lr){16-17}
\cmidrule(lr){18-19}
\cmidrule(lr){20-21}
\cmidrule(lr){22-23}
\cmidrule(lr){24-25}

\rowcolor{green!50}     % <----
\cellcolor{white}       % <----
   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mu$ }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$K/\phi$}\\
\cmidrule{2-25}
\rule{0pt}{3ex}\textit{$\xi=0$}& -0,046&-1,063&-0,058&-2,534&-0,072&-0,924&-0,053&-1,215&-0,053&-2,315&-0,053&-1,065&-0,131&-0,917&-0,090&-1,236&0,011& 0,000&  0,009&  0,000&  0,009&  0,000&  0,120&  3,270\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}$\xi=0.5$& -0,046 &-1,063&   -0,058& -2,534& -0,072& -0,924& -0,053& -1,215& -0,053& -2,315& -0,053& -1,065& -0,131& -0,917& -0,090& -1,236&-0,015&  -0,309& 0,000&  -0,222& 0,032&  0,437&  0,120&  3,270\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}$\xi=1$ &-0,053 &-1,147& -0,056& -2,490& -0,074& -0,950& -0,066& -1,442& -0,068& -2,780& -0,067& -1,276& -0,131& -0,917& -0,090& -1,236&-0,024&  -0,414& -0,004& -0,332& 0,046&  0,713&  0,120&  3,270\\
\rule{0pt}{3ex}$\xi=2$& -0,086 &-1,546& -0,089& -3,382& -0,100& -1,198& -0,092& -1,898& -0,094& -3,636& -0,092& -1,672& -0,131& -0,917& -0,113& -1,507&-0,036&  -0,551& -0,008& -0,442& 0,059&  0,949&  0,141&  3,880\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To my opinion, the result is not satisfactory. I would consider `tblr` table defined in the `tabullary` package. I can add possible solution using it, but do you may first change table code, that will produce showed image or change image accordingly to given MWE.

**Addendum:**

- From your comment follows, that your main problem is reorder rows in column headers and write correct content in the new second row! This really should not be problem, isn't it?
- In MWE below I made some changes. New table code is more simple and short and to my opinion make table more appealing and correct.
- For this I use `tabularray` package with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` (which call packages ot the same names).
- That table is a wee bit more readable, I took a liberty and change page layout with use `geometry` package. Wit it the page borders are decuced (and by this increase text area).

```
%\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}    % <--- new, 
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[font={large,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{ambiguity mu phi 101}
     \label{tab:ambiguity mu phi 101}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{                      % <----
\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec={  Q[l, mode=math, bg=yellow!50]
                        *{16}{Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]}    },
             row{1} = {guard, bg=yellow!50, mode=math},
             row{2} = {guard, font=\bfseries, bg=green!50},
             }
%    \toprule
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-25}
\SetCell[r=2]{bg=white}       % <----
    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi
    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi
    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi    & \mu   & K/\phi    \\
    \midrule
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2001 T1
        &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2001 T2
                &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2001 T3
                        &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2001 T4
                                &   & 
    \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2002 T1
        &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2002 T2
                &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2002 T3
                        &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2002 T4
                                &   & 
    \SetCell[c=2]{c} 2003 T1
        &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2003 T2
                &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2003 T3
                    &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  2003 T4      
                            &                       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3}      \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-7}      \cmidrule[lr]{8-9}
    \cmidrule[lr]{10-11}    \cmidrule[lr]{12-13}
    \cmidrule[lr]{14-15}    \cmidrule[lr]{16-17}
    \cmidrule[lr]{18-19}    \cmidrule[lr]{20-21}
    \cmidrule[lr]{22-23}    \cmidrule[lr]{24-25}

\xi=0
    &-0,046 & -1,063    &-0,058 & -2,534    &-0,072 & -0,924    &-0,053 & -1,215  
    &-0,053 & -2,315    &-0,053 & -1,065    &-0,131 & -0,917    &-0,090 & -1,236
    & 0,011 &  0,000    & 0,009 &  0,000    & 0,009 &  0,000    & 0,120 &  3,270    \\
\xi=0.5
    &-0,046 & -1,063    &-0,058 & -2,534    &-0,072 & -0,924    &-0,053 & -1,215
    &-0,053 & -2,315    &-0,053 & -1,065    &-0,131 & -0,917    &-0,090 & -1,236
    &-0,015 & -0,309    & 0,000 & -0,222    & 0,032 &  0,437    & 0,120 &  3,270    \\
\xi=1
    &-0,053 & -1,147    &-0,056 & -2,490    &-0,074 & -0,950    &-0,066 & -1,442
    &-0,068 & -2,780    &-0,067 & -1,276    &-0,131 & -0,917    &-0,090 & -1,236
    &-0,024 & -0,414    &-0,004 & -0,332    & 0,046 &  0,713    & 0,120 &  3,270    \\
\xi=2
    &-0,086 & -1,546    &-0,089 & -3,382    &-0,100 & -1,198    &-0,092 & -1,898
    &-0,094 & -3,636    &-0,092 & -1,672    &-0,131 & -0,917    &-0,113 & -1,507
    &-0,036 & -0,551    &-0,008 & -0,442    & 0,059 &  0,949    & 0,141 &  3,880    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for being here to help beginners , acutallly the main challenge for this table is how to keep 2001 T1 til 2021 T4 in one single table like showed in image, if you have time please can you propose a suggestion to change the table code to produce showed image

Comment: @haithem, than you should make your question more clear. I suppose, that this change is so elementary , that you with purpose  write MWE, Which produce different column headers. You only need to change rows order and merge cells content from the same column at successive header rows. Is this a problem? See addendum (will appear soon).

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderful contribution. My sincere gratitude for your assistance